# How to show `\` instead of special character `₩` in path separator command prompt?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

How to show `\` instead of special character `₩` in command prompt path, and it looks messy when some commands respond with bigger information:

**Currently, is showing:**

```
C:₩Users₩Username>
```

**Expecting:**

```
C:\Users\Username>
```

**System configurations:**

Edition: *Windows 10 Pro*

Processor: *Intel(R) Core(TM) i73667U CPU @ 2.00GHz 2.50GHz*

System Type: *64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor*

**Pointed arrow to character in screenshot:**

[image]

**Properties > Options and Font:**

[image]

**Active code page:** 949

Comment: `prompt $P$G` ...

Comment: Check your **[chcp too](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)** and  Windows key: **`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage`**

Comment: @itWasn'tMe, chcp: 949 and its available in CodePage, what can i do in this key?

Comment: Try edit using one option in the link **[chcp](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)** also, check other font in cmd properties..

Comment: That looks like the Korean Won not Japanese Yen. This is a **valid** path separator. See http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/10/12/479561.html

Comment: The author used to be responsible for the International Features in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `OEMCP` value in the registry using the command:

```bat
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" /v OEMCP /t reg_sz /d 949 /f
```

Replace `949` to one option:

[image]

- Read more at **[ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)**

Also, try to install more one font like **[Consolas](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17879)**

Answer (score 1):

Install **[English language packs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14236/windows-language-packs)** completely it may contain UTF-8 codes for "back slash" character.

Comment: Default language `English (United States)` is already there in my system settings, is there any specific language i have to install for this? or is it ok for now.